# Getting Expired Options Contract pricing from Interactive Brokers

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading, price, interactive-brokers

I am looking to reconstruct *Expired Options* pricing with the help of *ib_insync* library and Interactive Brokers available data..
Because IB provides OPTION_IMPLIED_VOLATILITY as an output for reqHistoricalData I was thinking proceeding this way:

- Have a **function** to infer Expired Options Contract Prices from Black-Scholes Model:

```
def black_scholes(stock_price,strike_price,vol,time,rate,right="Call"):
    d1 = (np.log(stock_price/strike_price) + (rate + 0.5* vol**2)*time)/(vol*np.sqrt(time))
    d2 = (np.log(stock_price/strike_price) + (rate - 0.5* vol**2)*time)/(vol*np.sqrt(time))
    nd1 = norm.cdf(d1)
    nd2 = norm.cdf(d2)
    n_d1 = norm.cdf(-1*d1)
    n_d2 = norm.cdf(-1*d2)
    if right.capitalize()[0] == "C":
        return round((stock_price*nd1) - (strike_price*np.exp(-1*rate*time)*nd2),2)
    else:
        return round((strike_price*np.exp(-1*rate*time)*n_d2) - (stock_price*n_d1),2)
```

- Using the **contract** on the underlying stock assuming I have a valid ib connection opened elsewhere in my code to retrieve the data

```
def get_stock_history(symbol,whattoshow_string):
            contract = Stock(symbol, 'SMART', 'USD')
            ib.reqMarketDataType(2)
            bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
                    contract,
                    endDateTime='',
                    durationStr='2 Y',
                    barSizeSetting='1 Hour',
                    whatToShow=whattoshow_string,
                    useRTH=True,
                    formatDate=1)
            ib.sleep(5)
            df = util.df(bars)
            df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] ).dt.date
            return df
```

- I also have a *handy function to compute maturity in the BSM* based on an hourly time decay:

```
def hourCount(DF, expiry):
      DF["maturity"] = ((dt.datetime.strptime(expiry, "%Y-%m-%d") - pd.to_datetime(DF.index))/pd.Timedelta(hours=1))/(365*24)
```

- I could then get the data as below assuming I have an expiration date and strike from elsewhere I wish to backtest:

```
strike = 148
expiration_date = '2022-12-02'
symbol = 'AAPL'
historicalData = get_stock_history(symbol,'ADJUSTED_LAST')
impVolData = get_stock_history(symbol,'OPTION_IMPLIED_VOLATILITY')


option_price_call = pd.DataFrame(columns=["open","high","low","close"])
option_price_put = pd.DataFrame(columns=["open","high","low","close"])
hourCount(historicalData, expiration_date)
hourCount(impVolData, expiration_date)
historicalData = historicalData [(historicalData["maturity"] > 0)]
impVolData = impVolData[(impVolData["maturity"] > 0)]
for column in ["open","high","low","close"]:
        option_price_call[column] = black_scholes(historicalData[column], strike, impVolData[column], historicalData["maturity"], 0.03,right="Call")
        option_price_put[column] = black_scholes(historicalData[column], strike, impVolData[column], historicalData["maturity"], 0.03,right="Put")
```

Would that be a good approach to reconstruct/backtest the Expired Options contract pricing or am I overlooking something here? and maybe a smarter way to achieve this operation?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions! (y)

Comment: You could try it on a non-expired chain and see how it goes in real time.

Comment: That was the next thing I did check, worked pretty well. Seems I need to optimize rate parameter + add a constant value in the mix and the result will be brilliant! :) alright, I will say good enough for my backtesting needs. Cheers!

Comment: Expired options contract = (stock price at close on that date or when exercised - strike price) x 100, you don't need Black-Scholes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IBKR does not keep expired options data as stated in their API docs on the limitations of historical data.

From: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_limitations.html

Unavailable Historical Data

Studies and indicators such as Weighted Moving Averages or Bollinger Bands are not available from the API. VWAP is available.
The other historical data limitations listed are general limitations for all trading platforms:

- Bars whose size is 30 seconds or less older than six months
- Expired futures data older than two years counting from the future's
  expiration date.
- Expired options, FOPs, warrants and structured products.
- End of Day (EOD) data for options, FOPs, warrants and structured
  products.
- Data for expired future spreads
- Data for securities which are no longer trading.
- Native historical data for combos. Historical data is not stored in
  the IB database separately for combos.; combo historical data in TWS
  or the API is the sum of data from the legs.
- Historical data for securities which move to a new exchange will
  often not be available prior to the time of the move.